# Android - Incoming call window is displayed behind Custom screen lock

Tags: android, service, lockscreen, android-broadcastreceiver, incoming-call

I'm developing Screen lock app . I can able to display the screen lock on the top of the device screen using this command "WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;"

```
public class LockScreen extends Activity{
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN|
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL|
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|
}
```

This is my receiver class

```
public class LockScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) || 
            action.equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED))
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, LockScreen.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
```

But my problem is I can't See the Incoming call Window when the custom lock screen is displayed. Incoming call window is displayed behind the custom lock screen. So that I can't receive the incoming calls until unlock my app. Is there any solution ?? In the normal lock screen apps -> They can attend the incoming calls and after attending that call, lock screen is displayed. How ????

Please help me !!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Comment: @Mike : No one answer my question. That's why I ask again. Please anyone help me . I'm completely blocked here !!